# Windows 7 won't identify network

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, connection

my Windows 7 machine has lost the ability to identify network connections and connect to the internet.  both my LAN and WLAN connections to the router are affected.  only thing I can think of happening is something occurring during my last iTunes update.  any one else encountering this?  I've been offline for days now.  very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with my network, would not identify either wireless or LAN. Read on another site to uninstall your network adaptor and reboot so windows will reinstall it. This worked for me and fixed the problem, might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `services.msc` (Windows + R), and look for Wired AutoConfig and WLAN AutoConfig, check if they are in Automatic (also, check if they are started).